# how to pass a variable to a Page Method Success callback function

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, pagemethods

i'm using asp.net PageMethods.So here is the way i make a call to the method from javascript

```
function hello()
{
    var a =10;
    PageMethods.SaveData(JSON.stringify(basicInfo), SaveSuccessCallback, SaveFailedCallback);
}
```

And here is my success call back condition

```
    function SaveSuccessCallback(response) {
    //handle success code here
    ShowEdit();
}
```

Now i wanted to handle the `ShowEdit()` based on a variable `a` which is in the hello function.
The issue is i don't know if its possible to pass `a` from `hello` to `SaveSuccessCallback` .
`Note:` i can't make `a` global.

Comment: Try to pass a to PageMethod and return is in result.

Comment: i thought about it but would require extra parsing on the web method side

Comment: I believe you should try @p.s.w.g post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):

```
var a = 10;
PageMethods.SaveData(
    JSON.stringify(basicInfo),
    function(response) { 
        SaveSuccessCallback(response);
        ShowEdit(a);
    }, SaveFailedCallback);

function SaveSuccessCallback(response) {
   //handle success code here
}
```

You may prefer to make this a bit cleaner by wrapping up the closure in another method:

```
PageMethods.SaveData(
    JSON.stringify(basicInfo), SaveSuccessCallback(10), SaveFailedCallback);

function SaveSuccessCallback(a) {
    return function(response) {
        //handle success code here
        ShowEdit(a);
    };
}
```